# Whatsapp Web Selenium Headless Chrome Not Working

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp, google-chrome-headless

I have a function that I use within a script that runs on [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) which logs into WhatsApp Web:

```
def send_message_whatsapp(contact,message):
    # Send to whatsapp

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    options.add_argument("--lang=en")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    #options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
    #options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
    #options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    #options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    #options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=whatsapp_profile")
    #options.add_argument("disable-extensions")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options=options)
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
    time.sleep(20)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("whatsappconfirmlogin.png")
    time.sleep(20)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Find the group name or whatsapp contact
    x_arg = f'//span[contains(@title,"{contact}")]'
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,x_arg)))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//span[@title="{contact}"]').click()
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file("whatsappconfirmgroupclick.png")
        inp_xpath = '//div[@class="_13NKt copyable-text selectable-text"][@data-tab="10"]'

        input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
            By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))

        for item in message:
            input_box.send_keys(item + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(2)
        button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_4sWnG')
        button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        # Close the application
        driver.quit()
        print("Successfully sent whatsapp message")
    except:
         print("Unable to find Whatsapp Group. Logging out...")
         driver.get_screenshot_as_file("whatsapptesterror.png")
         driver.quit()
```

The script used to work before the recent Whatsapp Web update. Now, it just fails to login. Looking at the saved screenshots, I can see that it tries to connect, but then it shows the message "Make sure your computer has an active internet connection".

[Connecting message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCSLv.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUrLf.png)

When I try to run a similar code on my local desktop where it does not run in headless chrome, it seems to work just fine.

```
def send_message_whatsapp(contact, message):

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
    options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=path')
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
    time.sleep(10)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    
    # Find the group name or whatsapp contact
    x_arg = f'//span[contains(@title,"{contact}")]'
    group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, x_arg)))
    group_title.click()
    inp_xpath = '//div[@class="_13NKt copyable-text selectable-text"][@data-tab="10"]'
    input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))
    for item in message:
        input_box.send_keys(item + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_4sWnG')
    time.sleep(2)
    button.click()
    
    # Close the application
    driver.close()
```

Comment: Could you try the default settings for Selenium on PythonAnyhwere and check if they're working for you? https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/

Comment: @caseneuve Just tried this but it still does not work. Keeps getting stuck at the connecting stage then prompts that my computer must have an active internet connection.

Comment: Don't know if this can help, but I'm facing the same problem so I will share my doubt. If I understood it right, using the headless option you are indirectly switching to another browser, not chrome (I think it should be phantomJS or something similar) and therefore the --user-data-dir is not the same you are specifying, hence the login information are in a different place. 

This is just my speculation, not tested yet, I'm working on it